# Expl3 syntax breaks biblatex xpatch patching

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, expl3, latex3, xpatch

Using `\ExplSyntaxOn` breaks `\xpatchbibmacro`. Can this be fixed, or will I just need to use `xpatch` commands elsewhere?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{1person,
  author    = {John Smith},
  title     = {Some Random Thing},
  date      = {1970}
}
@book{2people,
  author    = {John Smith and Bob Smith},
  title     = {Some Other Thing},
  date      = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
\ExplSyntaxOn % Removing this fixes it...
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}% Remove date's parentheses, add period before (/a/428193)
    {\printtext[parens]}{\setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\printtext}{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for `\ExplSyntaxOn`?

Comment: In my document I'm using it for `l3keys`, and there's a lot of conditional groups. `\ExplSyntaxOn` can't be put into groups, which forces me to split and double my conditionals.

Comment: That's expected.  Patching relies on everything having the “right” catcodes, and enabling `expl3` syntax changes quite a few of them, so patching breaks.  For example, if a command contains a `~` and then you patch it, it becomes a space in `expl3` syntax.

Comment: @TakingItCasual An example of what you need would be useful (in a new question).

Answer (score 3):

`\ExplSyntaxOn` changes the category code of several characters (space, `:`, `_`, `~`) and the patching routine may fail if the category codes are different from those at definition time.

Don't use `\xpatch...` under the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`.